# Import multiple .txt files from multiple folders into SSMS (SQL)

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

I have a folder (called WoWAH) with multiple folders in it. These folders are quarters of a year, and there are folders inside these for every day in that quarter. There are multiple `.txt` files in these folders that are times.

I want the fastest easiest way to import all of these `.txt` files into SQL Server as fast as possible (I am using SSMS).

An example of a text file is this:

```
Persistent_Storage = {

    [1] = "0, 01/01/06 23:59:39, 1,467, , 1, Orc, Warrior, Orgrimmar, no, 0",
    [2] = "0, 01/01/06 23:59:39, 1,921,19, 1, Orc, Shaman, Orgrimmar, no, 0",
    [3] = "0, 01/01/06 23:59:39, 1,1590,19, 9, Orc, Warlock, Durotar, no, 0",
    [515] = "0, 01/02/06 00:03:31, 45,1286,4, 60, Undead, Warrior, Arathi Basin, yes, 0",
    [516] = "0, 01/02/06 00:03:31, 45,1367,8, 60, Undead, Warrior, Arathi Highlands, yes, 0",}

RoundInfo = {

    [1] = "0, 1, 4, 281",
    [2] = "0, 2, 8, 402",
    [3] = "0, 3, 6, 268",
    [44] = "0, 44, 15, 135",
    [45] = "0, 45, 10, 135",}
```

I am really only interested in the `Persistent_Storage` rows of data. There are many files like this.

Overall, I want to pull the data from these files (just the first part of the file) and I want to do that for multiple files in a couple folders down. At the end of the day, I will be using this data in Tableau.

A file path example is...

```
D:\WoWAH\wowah\WoWAH\2006_01_03\2006-01-02
```

with the file title being `00-03-43`

Comment: You first need to define the table that it's going into. Does it have one column or ten or eleven?

Comment: I am only really looking to add 8 from the table, but I can do all 11 that are in it for simplicity and filter them out or delete them later.

Comment: Those files aren't easily consumed by any SQL Server import tools. There's no easy way to import them. To achieve the multi file / multi folder thing you can use SSIS (which might be included in your install). The real challenge is that this is not a tabular format. It's JSON. I can't think of a simple way to do this. This link shows a way of importing multiple JSON files into SQL Server but I don't know if it will be in a useful format. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/json/import-json-documents-into-sql-server